# How solve "This email address is already registered"

Tags: support, merge-accounts

When I edit my info, it shows me

> There was a problem updating your profile: This email address is already registered. If it belongs to you, log in above or visit our account recovery page to get access to this account

Then I search this problem, one solutions is merging with my old account, but I don't know how to merge.

How can I do this?

---

Someone told me to merge two accounts, but I dont't know the old profile link.

---

I have follow this link and recovery my account, but it doesn't work.when i edit my info,it still show me "There was a problem updating your profile: This email address is already registered. If it belongs to you, log in above or visit our account recovery page to get access to this account"

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregist

Comment: If you follow the duplicate links we provided you'll find that you need to visit [account recovery](http://stackoverflow.com/users/account-recovery) to regain access to your account.